# querying nested documents mongodb ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I am totally stumped!

I have the following document structure in a collection called "Gene", The sub-document I am interested in is "DrugDBI". The field that I wish to return is "drug_name" and nothing else; here it is "AAA" and "LLL".

```
{
 "ADR": [
{
  "adverse_type": "YYY",
}
],
"DrugDBI": [
{
  "cancer_type": "XXX",
  "drug_name": "AAAA",
},
{
  "cancer_type": "1405-87-4",
  "drug_name": "LLL",
}
]
"_id": "A2M",
"ts": { "$date": 1395239463625 }
}
```

AND

I need to extract just one field (i.e. "drug_name") from the sub-document whilst querying by id;

For eg;

My query id is @gene_v; here it is "A2M"

```
@gened = DB['Gene'].find({_id:@gene_v,fields:[{"DrugDBI" => {"$elemMatch" => {"$in" => "drug_name" } }}]}).to_a

puts "Drugs related to genes -> <#{@gened}>"
```

This obviously does not return any value. I appreciate any help.

The current output is;

```
Drugs related to genes -> <[]>
```

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB only serves "documents" and not arbitrary single field values nor array of field values.
So you will always have to extract an individual value from a document by key.
However, a major strength of MongoDB and documents is matching to programming language structures,
therefore empowering you to use your programming language.
You should consider your programming language as your primary tool of choice.

The MongoDB find query only allows simple projection/selection of top-level fields.
You can use the aggregation framework to do more complex extraction and transformation,
but I suggest that you go to your programming language first.
I hope that the following test illustrates all of this for you.

test.rb

```
require 'mongo'
require 'json'
require 'test/unit'

class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @coll = Mongo::MongoClient.new['test']['Gene']
    doc = JSON.parse <<-EOT
    { "ADR" : [{"adverse_type" : "YYY"}],
      "DrugDBI" : [{"cancer_type" : "XXX", "drug_name" : "AAAA"}, {"cancer_type" : "1405-87-4", "drug_name" : "LLL"}],
      "_id" : "A2M",
      "ts" : {"$date" : 1395239463625}
    }
    EOT
    @coll.remove
    @coll.insert(doc)
  end

  test "extract cancer drugs" do
    @gene_v = "A2M"

    doc = @coll.find({_id:@gene_v},fields:["DrugDBI"]).to_a.first
    @gened = doc["DrugDBI"].collect{|cancer_drug| cancer_drug["drug_name"]}
    assert_equal(["AAAA", "LLL"], @gened)
    puts "Drugs related to genes -> <#{@gened}>"

    doc = @coll.aggregate([
      {"$match" => {"_id" => @gene_v}},
      {"$unwind" => "$DrugDBI"},
      {"$project" => {"drug_name" => "$DrugDBI.drug_name"}},
      {"$group" => {"_id" => "$_id", "drug_name" => {"$push" => "$drug_name"}}}
    ]).to_a.first
    @gened = doc["drug_name"]
    assert_equal(["AAAA", "LLL"], @gened)
    puts "Drugs related to genes -> <#{@gened}>"
  end
end
```

$ ruby test.rb

```
Loaded suite test
Started
Drugs related to genes -> <["AAAA", "LLL"]>
Drugs related to genes -> <["AAAA", "LLL"]>
.

Finished in 0.010455 seconds.

1 tests, 2 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
```